# Why am I getting error when enum type variable is initialized in file scope?

Tags: c, enums, scope, initialization, variable-assignment

I am unable to understand the situation when I try to initialize the enum variable as global, i.e., outside of any scope. For example if I try to compile below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum suit {
    club = 0,
    diamonds = 10,
    hearts = 20,
    spades = 3
} card;

card = club;
int main() 
{ 
    printf("Size of enum variable = %d bytes", sizeof(card));   
    return 0;
}
```

Following compilation errors happen:

```
prog.c:9:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
card = club;
^
prog.c:9:1: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'card' [Wimplicit-int]
prog.c:9:1: error: conflicting types for 'card'
prog.c:8:3: note: previous declaration of 'card' was here
} card;
  ^
```

But when I put the initialization within the main() scope , no error occurs like the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum suit {
    club = 0,
    diamonds = 10,
    hearts = 20,
    spades = 3
} card;

int main() 
{
    card = club;
    printf("Size of enum variable = %d bytes", sizeof(card));   
    return 0;
}
```

Output is :

```
Size of enum variable = 4 bytes
```

Comment: `card = club` is a statement, and you can't have statements outside a function body.

Answer (score 2):

Your first declares a global variable named `club` of type `enum suit`, however you cannot initialize a global variable on another line outside of a function - you must do it on the same line, like so:

```
enum suit {
    club = 0,
    diamonds = 10,
    hearts = 20,
    spades = 3
} card = club;
```

I feel your code would be more readable if you moved the `enum club` definition away from the variable declaration:

```
enum suit {
    club = 0,
    diamonds = 10,
    hearts = 20,
    spades = 3
};

enum suit card = club;
```

The extra `enum` keyword is because C (unlike C++) has a different namespace for each kind of type - so you can have `enum foo` and `struct foo` in the same project without the names colliding because `enum` and `struct` type names exist in different namespaces.

(I'm personally not a fan of using `typedef` - but feel free to go with that if you choose).

Comment: Nitpick: `initialize a global variable on another line`..we have a shorter name for that, assignment. :)

Comment: @Dai I am not sure about your first two statements. Since we can declare a global variable and define it separately on two different line without any fear of compilation error. But I am not sure if this case is valid for enum or maybe structure variable. If it is not valid then there I would like to know why it is not valid.

Comment: " Since we can declare a global variable and define it separately on two different line without any fear of compilation error." - correct, however in your original code the line where you set the value of `card` is *not* a definition.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because

```
  card = club;
```

is an **[assignment statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science))** , which needs to be in block scope (some function body) not in file scope, not an **initialization**.

If you use [initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_(programming)), it'll work.

Also note the extra changes

- `int main()` should be `int main(void)`
- `sizeof` yields a `size_t`, so you should use `%zu` format specifier to print the result.

Example

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum suit {
    club = 0,
    diamonds = 10,
    hearts = 20,
    spades = 3
} card = club;

int main(void) 
{ 
    printf("Size of enum variable = %zu bytes", sizeof(card));   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is it so? Might be because the guaranteed ordered execution starts from `main()` function?

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal Yep, you put any runtime statement in file scope and nobody knows when it should be executed, so it's illegal.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Unrelated but won't main() be the same as main(void) since it is a definition?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya In C99 you must specify `foo(void)` to indicate a function has no parameters. If you omit `void` it's not considered a declaration/prototype, but a definition, and then things get funny: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43042/in-c-not-using-void-if-a-function-does-not-accept-any-argument-is-a-potential

Comment: @Dai, but it IS a definition. Not a declaration.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I don't think it should be an assignment issue here. That thing you are saying is true when compiler don't know what value the global variable to assign with. But here the case is different as the value with which I am assigning the enum variable is of const type and compiler do know its value beforehand. If you see the compilation error log, it is the type conflict issue which somehow Dai is able to solve it. But still question is why we can't declare and define enum variable separately.

Comment: @VaibhavGautam You're free to think otherwise, but as far as I know, assignment statements cannot exist in file scope, that's the syntax and sematics.